# Iron Condor Chart

Tags: reactjs, charts, highcharts, trading, apexcharts

How to create Iron-Condor chart that contains Area, Line and Bar chart combined?

I have used libraries like Apexcharts and HighCharts, but not getting anything that provides these three graphs together.

Attached an Image for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sHkn.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely achieve such a chart in Highcharts. You can combine certain types of series without any problems:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        width: 400
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
  series: [{
        type: 'column',
        color: 'green',
        data: [25, 10, 60, 42, 32, 76, 21, 111, 5, 12]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        color: 'red',
        data: [42, 2, 32, 76, 21, 47, 97, 101, 21, 7]
    }, {
        type: 'spline',
        data: [{x: 0, y:30}, {x: 2, y:60}, {x: 4.5, y:0}, {x: 6.5, y:70}, {x: 9, y:20}]
    }, {
    type: 'area',
        color: 'black',
        dashStyle: 'LongDash',
        fillColor: '#00ff0050',
        negativeFillColor: '#ff000050',
    data: [-50, -50, 120, 120, -50, -50, 125, 125, -50, -50]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6p9ayk3z/